# Store Android Switch Value

Tags: java, android

My activity has a switch for a yes/no question. How do I store the selected choice in the DB so it can be viewed later.

I have created the column in the DB but it doesn't seem to be storing the value.
Ex: Does Mark like Icecream? - `Switch=Y`

Currently:

```
mIcecream = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.Icecream);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be storing the switch state as a boolean in sharedpreferences rather than storing the value in a database. The state would be persisted that way as well. To store a boolean, you can do this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
prefs.edit().putBoolean("state", **your switch state**).commit();
```

If you have a lot of switch states to store, then I suggest you store the boolean state as 0/1 value for false/true or vice versa in SQLite database.